# Compare attribute values and texts between two xml files and write to file in Python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I know that there are already tons of similar questions about this topic, but none of the solutions seem to work for me.
I have two files that look like this:

**strings_src.xml:**

```
<resources>
   <string name="app_name">SkidSteerLoader</string>
   <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
   <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
   <string name="title_activity_speed">SpeedActivity</string>
</resources>
```

**strings_da.xml:**

```
<resources>
   <string name="title_activity_speed">SpeedActivity</string>
   <string name="app_name">SkidSteerLoader</string>
   <string name="hello_world">Hej Verden!</string>
</resources>
```

The structure is quite similar, but there may be less  item in the second file.
I need to compare the string names and the values for each string: if the string name is the same and the string value is the same, I need to add something like *traduci = "yes"* in the string tag of the second file.
Something like:

```
 <resources>
   <string name="title_activity_speed" traduci = "yes">SpeedActivity</string>
   <string name="app_name" traduci = "yes">SkidSteerLoader</string>
   <string name="hello_world">Hej Verden!</string>
 </resources>
```

I have already tried to use a combination of for loops and if conditions in python using the element tree, but I'm clearly doing something wrong there

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree_src = ET.parse('strings_src.xml')
root_src = tree_src.getroot()
tree_tar = ET.parse('strings_da.xml')
root_tar = tree_tar.getroot()

for child_src in root_src:
    for child_tar in root_tar:
        if child_src.tag == child_tar.tag and child_src.text != child_tar.text:
            child_tar.set = ('traduci', 'yes')

tree_tar.write('output_da.xml')
```

What can I do?

Comment: If you can use lxml instead of ElementTree, it's pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through each file separately, build a dictionary with the first file dict = {sourceline:elem_text}, then while iterating through the second file compare each line against the dict in memory and make changes as necessary.